# Difference between Velocity and AppFabric

Tags: .net, appfabric

I have a few questions that may be useful for others to get answered too.

1. Is Velocity stable? I can only find CTP3. When is it due for final release?
2. What is the difference between AppFabric and Velocity?
3. What are the requirements on server with regards to Services installed, ports in firewalls, etc.?

Comment: You may want take a look at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/velocity/thread/4fd844f6-3530-4115-8982-d7562e699627 for some gotcha's/requirements for installed servicesnand open ports etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out so I'm sharing my findings:

1. AppFabric is out of beta and seems stable, but I'm finding a lot of errors on the way to stability. Yet to see this in stable action.
2. Velocity was put into AppFabric.
3. The configuration tool will ask you for ports (TCP 22233->22236 or something) and open the local firewall for you. Some of the powershell commands use other windows services though.

Answer (score 10):

Velocity has been rolled into Windows Server AppFabric.
AppFabric has 2 components. one part is the distributed caching (aka Velocity) and the other part is service host (i.e. for WCF or WF).

The other info that you want can be found in the following installation guide: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/info.aspx?na=40&p=4&SrcDisplayLang=en&SrcCategoryId=&SrcFamilyId=467e5aa5-c25b-4c80-a6d2-9f8fb0f337d2&u=http%3a%2f%2fgo.microsoft.com%2ffwlink%2f%3fLinkID%3d184618

Answer (score 0):

You can install the RTM version of AppFabric through the Web Platform Installer at http://www.iis.net/webpi (you may need to enable the Enterprise tab in the options), or you can download the installer [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=467e5aa5-c25b-4c80-a6d2-9f8fb0f337d2).